# p>>>n problem how to navigate?

Tags: regression, large-data, bioinformatics

I have a DNA methlation data for 32 samples. For each sample I have DNA methylation avaialble for >10000's of cpg bases (ie C nucleotides on DNA). I also have gene expression data from which I have estimated tumor proportion of each sample. I am trying to regress tumor proportion against DNA methylation loci's. I intend to find which of the DNA methylation loci predict the tumor proportion well.

As I went about in solving this problem I thought linear regression would be the most straightforward way to go about it. Only to realize that my data suffers from a p>>>n problem as I only have 32 samples (and thus tumor proportion for only 32 observations).

If I use all the DNA methlation loci information it gives me junk output and makes the model only from 16 DNA methlation loci with very high intercept value.

I was wondering if it is even worth doing regression on this problem. And How to go about it. How would folks in this community approach this problem. Is there an exhaustive text on variable selection (applied) that someone could point me to.

At the end of the day all I need is DNA methlation loci that are best predictors of tumor proportion.

A multi-variate variant of this problem is if I have proportions from multiple cell types and I am trying to predict that then how to go about it as well.

Comment: To be honest: I am pessimistic! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_in_ten_rule per feature you should have 10 observations... Now you may get around this but only if you are able to add prior knowledge/external knowledge (and possibly a lot). If somebody knows better please correct me - and I am not talking about artificial counter examples like drawing a line through exactly 2 points ...

Comment: Can you generate synthetic data out of this 32 samples? One could add different level noise in educated manner to generate new samples out of "real samples".

Comment: @patagonicus this will substantially increase variance which is essentially the limiting issue with large p. Alternately one could use ridge or lasso which adds a little bias but decreases variance by a LOT.

Comment: There are "smart" algorithms that preserve statistical properties, i.e., such as CGAN,  applied to solar flare synthetic data generation  [link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00521-022-07361-8). Though not sure if this can be transferable to DNA dataset.

Comment: This is not really a statistically tractable problem. You'll find a good explanation of the issues and possible options (and their caveats!) by Frank Harrell [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/hdata.html). He also has a very elucidating example [here](https://www.fharrell.com/post/badb/#bootstrap-ranking-example) of a problem much smaller than yours, where all they could say about the 'best' marker was that it wasn't among the 10% worst.

Comment: If you want to go down the regression route then you could try the lasso or SLOPE, both of which have easy to use R packages.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, with any sort of regression, you are violating the basic assumption of needing 10 records (samples, objects) for each feature or predictor you have in the model.  Thus, for mRNA expression of 10 transcripts, you need 100 samples.

Why don't you consider "discretizing" or splitting the proportion of tumor into a low/high (0,1) value based on a median cut, as well as splitting expression into or low/high (0,1) using a median cut, and then run a 2x2 chi-squared test for each transcript.  This approach removes a gradient-based view on what's going on biologically over the dose-response relationship between tumor percentage and expression level - something that you or anyone else may know little about if your data are exploratory (novel). An alternative is given below.

At the very least I would probably recode the tumor percent values into low/high (0,1) based on using a median cut, and then run a Mann-Whitney test for each transcript.  I wouldn't use t-test, because at this level of analysis you haven't screened for the presence of extreme outlier expression values - which would strongly bias the t-test (which is based on averages).  Mann-Whitney is based on ranks, so outliers are recoded to much lower integer values.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a preliminary characterisation that will be (should be) followed up upon by a second designed study, or a series of studies. You do not need to make firm conclusions, but characgterise the data carefully. If it is possible, make reasonable hypotheses to be later tested with new data.

Consider ranking the genes (or bases, I'm not sure what the unit of interest actually is) on the basis of their effect size or p-value or the like and decide on how many of them should be tested using a designed study with more data and fewer candidate genes.